# Remove <div> and <p> tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following piece of HTML code.

```
<ul class="system_messages">
    <li class="green">
        <span class="ico"></span>
        <strong class="system_title">
            <div class="ui-widget actionMessage">

                <!--The following <div> along with <p> is required to be removed-->

                <div class="ui-state-highlight ui-corner-all" style="padding: 0.3em 0.7em; margin-top: 20px;"> 
                    <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-info" style="float: left; margin-right: 0.3em;"></span>
                        <span>Updation at id 33 has been made successfully.</span></p>
                </div>

            </div>
        </strong>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I need to remove the specified tags in the comment `<div>` and `<p>` but two child tags of that `<div>` i.e two `<span>` tags should not be removed. Is this possible?

<sub>The outermost `<div>` tag (`<div class="ui-widget actionMessage">`) is generated dynamically.</sub>

Comment: Using what technology? HTML alone? Sure, edit the code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you allowed using JavaScript or jQuery? If so, a jQuery solution may look like this:

```
$('span.ui-icon.ui-icon-info').unwrap().unwrap();
```

Comment: The jQuery selector uses CSS classes (it does not have an `id` of an element). How does this selector pick up `<p>` and `<div>` and then unwrap them? May I know?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can remove the `div` and `p` tags without removing the `span` tag.

Here is the fiddle after removing:

http://jsfiddle.net/gdSgS/

As the class associated with div and the `<p>` tags are removed, there will be some change in alignment. You can retain it by applying the class to some other compatible tags if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

```
function cleanDIVP($text){
        $strip_tags = "p|div";
        $text = preg_replace("#<\s*\/?(".$strip_tags.")\s*[^>]*?>#im", '', $text);
        return $text;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use setInterval function to unwrap the span element.

```
setInterval(function (){ $('.system_title span').unwrap();  }, 10)
```